# xmpp file upload using smack

Tags: xmpp, chat, ejabberd, smack

i am unable to upload file on xmpp using smack client android. slot.puturl() returns "https://localhost:7443/httpfileupload/27c97df7-dbbf-47ff-b19a-3ac624e51cf0/1.jpg"

```
 HttpFileUploadManager manager = HttpFileUploadManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection);
    try {
        Slot slot = manager.requestSlot(path, 10000);

        uploadFileToSlot(new File(path), slot);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for after very deep research.

That HttpFileUploadManager is only for requesting slot from server.

Once you got slot request url upload file using httpclient or okhttpclient.
For okhttpclient:

1. You need to configure sslSocketFactory by mtm or certificatepinning.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder();
SSLContext sslContext = JavaPinning.forPin(<PINNING_VALUE>);
okHttpClientBuilder.writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

okHttpClientBuilder.sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory(), JavaPinning.trustManagerForPin(<PINNING_VALUE>));
OkHttpClient client = okHttpClientBuilder.build();
```

2. initiate okhttpclient and add file like.

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(slot.getPutUrl())
    .put(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), files))
        .build();
```

3. Now lets begin to upload.

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(final Call call, final IOException e) {
        // Handle the error
        Log.i(log, "error " + e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(final Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            // Handle the error
            Log.i(log, "errored " + response);
        }
        Log.i(log, "success " + response);
        // Upload successful
    }
});
```

Hope it helps you.